# Eclipse-indigo "assign working sets" not available

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I am using Eclipse Indigo, with the Plug-in Development Perspective on a linux box. 
I have been using my current workspace for months. Suddenly this morning, when I brought up my workspace, I don't see the working sets that I have set up and when I right click on a project, I don't see "Assign Working Sets" as an option. 
I have restarted Eclipse using eclipse -clean. 
I have verified that my "Top Level Elements" is set to "Working Sets". 
I selected "Select Working Set" and can see that the names of my working sets are all available. If I select the "Selected Working Sets" button and select all, nothing shows in the Project Explorer. 
I would like to get back the link between my projects and my working sets but I don't know what to try next.

Comment: On my system 'Assign Working Sets' only appears in the context menu when using 'Package Explorer' not 'Project Explorer'

Comment: Pre-coffee, I apparently confused Project Explorer with Package Explorer so thanks for setting me straight. I had a bit of an issue finding "Package Explorer" again, but was able to open it with WIndow -> Show View -> Other...-> Java -> Package Explorer. I'm not sure why it disappeared on me in the first place.